# How add download manager in webview android

Tags: java, android, webview, download

```
package sawatop.com.tubemate; 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.app.AlertDialog; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.content.DialogInterface; 
import android.graphics.Bitmap; 
import android.net.ConnectivityManager; 
import android.net.NetworkInfo; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.KeyEvent; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.webkit.WebView; 
import android.webkit.WebViewClient; 
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.ProgressBar; 
import android.widget.Toast; 
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest; 
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView; 

public class DetailsActivity extends Activity { 
    private ProgressBar progressBar; 
    private WebView web; 
    private WebView web2; 
    private String url = ""; 
    private String url2 = ""; 
    private Button buttonClose; 
    private long lastPressedTime; 
    private static final int PERIOD = 60000; 

    @Override 
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) { 
            switch (event.getAction()) { 
                case KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                    if (event.getDownTime() - lastPressedTime < PERIOD) { 
                        finish(); 
                    } else { 
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click agin to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                        lastPressedTime = event.getEventTime(); 
                    } return true; 
                } 
            } 
        return false; 
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details); 
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView); 
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build(); 
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest); 
        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) { 
            url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("KEY_INTENT_URL"); 
        } 
        buttonClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
        buttonClose.setText("\u0623\u063a\u0644\u0627\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0627\u0641\u0630\u0629");
        buttonClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish(); 
            } 
        }); 
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress); 
        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); web2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview2);
        web2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        if (hasConnection(this)) { 
            web.loadUrl(url);
            web2.loadUrl(url2); 
            web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
                @Override 
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) { 
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon); 
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url2, favicon); 
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                } 

                @Override 
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url); 
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url2); 
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                    // actionBar.show(); 
                } 
            }); 
        } else { 
            DisplayAlertDialog(this, "Internet connection not available. \nPlease check your internet connection."); 
        } 
    } 
    public static boolean hasConnection(Context context) { 
        boolean isNetAvailable = false; 
        if (context != null) { 
            final ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
        if (mConnectivityManager != null) { 
            boolean mobileNetwork = false; 
            boolean wifiNetwork = false; 
            boolean mobileNetworkConnecetd = false; 
            boolean wifiNetworkConnecetd = false; 
            final NetworkInfo mobileInfo = mConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE); 
            final NetworkInfo wifiInfo = mConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI); 
            if (mobileInfo != null) { 
                mobileNetwork = mobileInfo.isAvailable(); 
            } 
            if (wifiInfo != null) { 
                wifiNetwork = wifiInfo.isAvailable(); 
            } 
            if (wifiNetwork || mobileNetwork) { 
                if (mobileInfo != null) 
                    mobileNetworkConnecetd = mobileInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting(); 
                wifiNetworkConnecetd = wifiInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting(); 
            } 
            isNetAvailable = (mobileNetworkConnecetd || wifiNetworkConnecetd); 
         } 
      } 
      return isNetAvailable; 
    } 

    private void DisplayAlertDialog(Context context, String Message) {
      AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); 
      alertDialog.setTitle(web.getTitle()); 
      alertDialog.setMessage(Message); 
      alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              dialog.dismiss(); 
          } 
      }); 
      alertDialog.show(); 
    } 
}
```

how i can add download file from this url

https://r1---sn-ab5l6nes.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?type=video%2F3gpp%3B+codecs%3D%22mp4v.20.3%2C+mp4a.40.2%22&signature=87B209A955C7A0978E5BE6375A33A295321C40FC.5780263682592D055D67206BBEB032021CE7A4C3&dur=332.463&mt=1444993525&mv=m&fexp=9408710%2C9412914%2C9414764%2C9414810%2C9415821%2C9416126%2C9416524%2C9416729%2C9417707%2C9418204%2C9418401%2C9419445%2C9419892%2C9420772%2C9421165%2C9421606%2C9422951&ms=au&source=youtube&mm=31&mn=sn-ab5l6nes&upn=2KMaHc3Sop8&lmt=1416629503243021&mime=video%2F3gpp&itag=17&sver=3&key=yt6&ipbits=0&pl=23&requiressl=yes&gcr=us&expire=1445015194&id=d00aa70927648d0d&sparams=dur%2Cgcr%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&initcwndbps=2678750&ip=158.69.202.190&fallback_host=tc.v15.cache5.googlevideo.com&quality=small&title=Eminem---Guts-Over-Fear-ft-Sia